# Having two UITableViewCells with different background gradient

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin

I have a custom cell with a gradient background. In the constructor of my custom cell I have:

```
this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

RectangleF cellFrame = new RectangleF (this.Bounds.X, this.Bounds.Y, this.Bounds.Width, 60);

CAGradientLayer gradientForStateNormal = new CAGradientLayer ();
CAGradientLayer gradientForStateSelected = new CAGradientLayer ();
gradientForStateNormal.Frame = cellFrame;
gradientForStateSelected.Frame = cellFrame;
gradientForStateNormal.NeedsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true;
gradientForStateNormal.MasksToBounds = true;
gradientForStateNormal.Colors = new CGColor[]{ UIColor.White.CGColor, UIColor.White.CGColor, UIColor.FromRGB(128,128,128).CGColor };
gradientForStateSelected.NeedsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true;
gradientForStateSelected.MasksToBounds = true;
gradientForStateSelected.Colors = new CGColor[]{ UIColor.FromRGB(16,16,16).CGColor, UIColor.White.CGColor, UIColor.White.CGColor };

UIView selectedBackgroundView = new UIView (cellFrame);
UIView backgroundView = new UIView (cellFrame);
backgroundView.Layer.InsertSublayer (gradientForStateNormal, 0);
selectedBackgroundView.Layer.InsertSublayer (gradientForStateSelected, 0);

this.BackgroundView = backgroundView;
this.SelectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;
```

This works for a single gradient background color. Now I have cells which should get a different gradient background color. Therefore I implemented `WillDisplay` and set my gradients. Two problem remains:

1. Everytime two UIViews are created
2. Through cell reuse every 9th cell has now the new gradient background color. This shouldn't happen.

What are my options?

One thing which comes up to my mind is to use another custom cell class with a different reuse identifier. But I don't want to manage two custom cell classes with the same code except different color. What solutions do you have for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found any other solution. This is what I'm using now:

1. I copied my custom table view cell and made a new class out of it.
2. In `GetCell` I ask after my criteria and than I'm creating and returning the cell separately:

   ```
   public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath){
       // your criteria here
       if (read) {
           var cell = (UnreadCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell (UnreadCell.cellIdentifier);
           cell.UpdateCell (...);

           cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
           cell.SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;

           return cell;
       } else {
           var cell = (ReadCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell (ReadCell.cellIdentifier);
           cell.UpdateCell (...);

           cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
           cell.SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;

           return cell;
       }
   }
   ```

Now I have duplicate code everywhere: In the copied custom table view cell and in `GetCell`.

One other option I thought of is to subclass my custom table view cell class. But I didn't get it working. Don't know if a special constructor (passing the color) or something like a factory method would do it better.